# How can I cut down the number of queries?

Tags: python, django

This code is currently executing about 50 SQL queries:

```
c = Category.objects.all()

categories_w_rand_books = []

for category in c:
    r = Book.objects.filter(author__category=category).order_by('?')[:5]

    categories_w_rand_books.append((category, r))
```

I need to cut down the number of used queries to the minimum to speed up things and do not cause server load.

Basically, I have three models: Category, Author, Book. The Author belong to the Category (not books) and I need to get a list of all categories with 5 random books under each one.

Comment: don't try to get it on code side, rather try to monitor database...

Comment: More code could be useful (what is that `e`?). Could you also please include a few of the repeated queries?

Comment: Try optimizing queries (joining them) & save the result into variable...

Comment: @ThomasOrozco e was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: There's not really a great way to do a bunch of *different* random selections.

Comment: Post your models for a best answer in return

Comment: SQL optimization often depends on the model.

Comment: Efficiently doing random selections in a table with a `where` constrain is hard. If you don't need to run your code very often (or you can cache it) your solution is much more simpler.

Comment: Will this help? Use a group_by on category and retrieve top 'N' (ie 5) records per category.. Follow this [link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) to create your query. Not sure how to do it in Django though

Comment: Can you edit your question with the description of your Models?

Comment: what's causing `50` sql queries? `for category in c:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer single query and are using `MySQL`, check [the excellent link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) provided by @Crazyshezy in his comment.
For `PostgreSQL` backends, a possible query is (assuming there are non-nullable `FK` relationships from `Book` to `Author` and from `Author` to `Category`):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT book_table.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY RANDOM()) AS rn 
    FROM book_table INNER JOIN author_table ON book_table.author_id = author_table.id
) AS sq 
WHERE rn <= 5
```

You could then wrap it inside a `RawQuerySet` to get `Book` instances

```
from collections import defaultdict
qs = Book.objects.raw("""The above sql suited for your tables...""")
collection = defaultdict(list)
for obj in qs:
    collection[obj.category_id].append(obj)

categories_w_rand_books = []
for category in c:
    categories_w_rand_books.append((category, collection[category.id]))
```

You may not want to run this query for each request directly w/o some caching.

Furthermore, your code generates at most 50*5=250 `Book`s, randomly, I just wonder why because it seems too many for a single page. Are items displayed as tabs or something else? Perhaps you could reduce the counts of SQLs by doing Ajax, or simplify the requirement?

*Update*

To use `book.author` w/o triggering more than another query, try `prefetch_related_objects`

```
from django.db.models.query import prefetch_related_objects
qs = list(qs) # have to evaluate at first
prefetch_related_objects(qs, ['author'])
# now instances inside qs already contain cached author instances, and
qs[0].author # will not trigger an extra query
```

The above code prefetches authors in batch and fills them into the `qs`. This just adds another query.

Comment: Your code cut down the queries into about half. But my template are like this: {% for category books in categories %}
    {% for book in books %}
        ...
        {{ book.author }}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %} -- so Django is still going to the database to fetch on {{ book.author }}

Comment: @adamsilver try `prefetch_related_objects` or manually do the fetching and filling process.

Comment: This is returning None:    raw_qs = list(qs)
    eee = prefetch_related_objects(raw_qs, ['author'])
    print eee

Comment: Thanks, it worked with your last update but the book ID is overwritten by the author ID! {{ book.title }} works but {{ book.id }} gives the author ID!

Comment: @adamsilver I tried and it works for me. Please elaborate the relative query and models

Comment: the code is perfectly working, the problem now is the variables being overwritten. As I mentioned: book ID is overwritten by the author ID! {{ book.title }} works but {{ book.id }} gives the author ID!

Comment: @adamsilver Aha, I'm almost certain it's because of typo in the SQL, sorry! Inside the `SQL`, the second `SELECT *` should looks like `SELECT book_table.*` or else the `id` column of the `author_table` could be selected and override the `book.id`... check the edit.

Comment: That gives "'Book' object has no attribute 'category_id'"

Comment: @adamsilver alright，then just append ',category_id' to 'SELECT book_table.*' to make it into books

Comment: It stopped working with Python 3. prefetch_related_objects(qs, ['author']) gives me: unhashable type: 'list'. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help you because I don't know the details and context of your problem, but using `order_by('?')` is very inefficient, specially with some DB back-ends.

For displaying entities with a bit of randomness I use this approach, using a custom filter:

```
@register.filter
def random_iterator(list, k):
    import random
    class MyIterator:
        def __init__(self, obj, order):
            self.obj=obj
            self.cnt=0
            self.order = order

        def __iter__(self):
            return self

        def next(self):
            try:
                result=self.obj.__getitem__(self.order[self.cnt])
                self.cnt+=1
                return result
            except IndexError:
                raise StopIteration

    if list is None:
        list = []
    n = len(list)
    k = min(n, k)
    return MyIterator(list, random.sample(range(n), k))
```

The code in my Django view is something like this:

```
RAND_BOUND = 50    
categories = Category.objects.filter(......)[RAND_BOUND]
```

And, I use it in my template in this way:

```
{% for cat in categories|random_iterator:5 %}
 <li>{{ cat }}</li>             
{% endfor %}
```

This code will pick 5 random categories of a (reduced) set of `RAND_BOUND`.
This is not THE perfect solution, but hope it helps.